# Выборка из таблицы БД со связью 1 ко многим

Tags: mysql, база-данных, select

Есть таблица `products` и таблица `assortiment`, они связаны **"1 ко многим"**, т.е. каждой записи таблицы `products` соответствует 1 или несколько записей из таблицы `assortiment`.

`assortiment` - это различные вариации одного товара (например цвета, размеры и т.п.).

У `products` есть поле `id`, а у assortiment есть поля `id`, `product_id` и `sklak`. По `product_id` ассортимент связывается с товаром, а `sklad` - это остаток товаров такого типа (цвета, размера и т.п.) на складе.

Задача сделать выборку из таблицы `products`, но только тех записей, для которых хотя бы 1 ассортимент имеет не нулевое значение поля `sklad`.

Вопрос, каким образом построить условие для запроса `SELECT` ?

Хотя бы наведите на мысль или задайте наводящие вопросы, я постараюсь конкретизировать свой вопрос ;)

Comment: Как насчет JOIN?

Comment: Да я понимаю что нужен JOIN, только не могу сообразить, как сформировать такое условие, чтобы отсеить товары, для которых весь ассортимент имеет нулевой остаток

Comment: Как-то так, наверное: 'SELECT product.name AS "Product" 
FROM assortiment JOIN products ON assortiment.productid=product.id
WHERE sklad !=0'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT products.*
FROM products
JOIN assortiment on products.id = assortiment.products_id
WHERE assortiment.sklad
```

Будут выведены все products, которым соответствует хотя бы одна запись в assortiment, имеющая assortiment.sklad не ноль и не NULL.

Comment: Спасибо! Примерно так я и сделал, только в моём случае больше подходит LEFT JOIN

Comment: @АнатолийШевелев *в моём случае больше подходит LEFT JOIN* Вот с этого места поподробнее. Почему? Мне кажется, что Вы делаете ошибку - по причине непонимания, что такое LEFT JOIN. Или реальная задача настолько отличается от описанной в вопросе, что даже непонятно, как мой ответ вообще смог помочь...

Comment: Ну конечно данный пример очень сильно упрощён, в реальном запросе много различных условий и несколько LEFT JOIN и я посчитал правильным, что в данном случае тоже лучше использовать именно LEFT JOIN

Comment: @АнатолийШевелев LEFT надо использовать только там, где он реально нужен. Например, если в моём запросе написать LEFT JOIN - то по факту связывание всё равно будет INNER из-за условия во WHERE, но серверу придётся проделать лишнюю работу по добавлению пустых строк при связывании и удалению их всех при отборе. Смысл? от сервера надо, чтобы он работал, а не чтобы он зае***ся...

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй так (поле `product_id` под свои ключи переименуй):

```
SELECT p.*
FROM products p
```

И далее либо

```
INNER JOIN assoriments a ON a.prodict_id = p.product_id
WHERE sklad > 0
```

Либо

```
INNER JOIN assoriments a ON a.prodict_id = p.product_id AND a.sklad > 0
WHERE a.id IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: *не нулевое значение поля sklad* и `sklad > 1` - это немножко разные вещи...

Comment: Этот вариант не сильно отличается от варианта выше, единственное, к такому варианту ```INNER JOIN assoriments a ON a.prodict_id = p.product_id AND a.sklad > 0``` всё равно нужно добавить условие, например, ```where a.id IS NOT NULL```, иначе запрос выдаст все записи